# `StateNotifierProvider` test doesn't catch initial state

Tags: dart, riverpod

I'm writing unit tests for my `StateNotifierProvider` but I'm facing a strange scenario when testing the failure scenario. For some reason, the unit test is not capturing the initial state. Here's the provider implementation:

```dart
final paymentBundleVM = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<PaymentBundleVM, PaymentBundleState>(
  (ref) => PaymentBundleVM(ref.read(getPaymentBundleUseCase), ref.read(createPaymentBundleUseCase)),
  dependencies: [getPaymentBundleUseCase, createPaymentBundleUseCase],
  name: 'paymentBundleVM',
);

class PaymentBundleVM extends StateNotifier<PaymentBundleState> {
  PaymentBundleVM(this._getBundleUseCase, this._createBundleUseCase) : super(PaymentBundleLoading()) {
    unawaited(_loadDependencies());
  }

  final GetPaymentBundleUseCase _getBundleUseCase;
  final CreatePaymentBundleUseCase _createBundleUseCase;

  Future<void> _loadDependencies() async {
    try {
      final bundle = await _getBundleUseCase.run();
      if (mounted) {
        if (bundle != null)
          state = PaymentBundleLoaded(bundle);
        else
          state = PaymentBundleDisabled();
      }
    } on BaseException catch (exception) {
      if (mounted) state = PaymentBundleFailedLoadingState(exception);
    }
  }
}

abstract class PaymentBundleState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class PaymentBundleLoading extends PaymentBundleState {}

class PaymentBundleDisabled extends PaymentBundleState {}

class PaymentBundleLoaded extends PaymentBundleState {
  PaymentBundleLoaded(this.bundle);

  final PaymentBundle bundle;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [...super.props, bundle];
}

class PaymentBundleFailedLoadingState extends PaymentBundleState {
  PaymentBundleFailedLoadingState(this.exception);

  final BaseException exception;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [...super.props, exception];
}
```

And here's my unit test code:

```dart
void main() {
  final getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock = GetPaymentBundleUseCaseMock();
  final createPaymentBundleUseCaseMock = CreatePaymentBundleUseCaseMock();

  late ProviderContainer container;

  final fakeBundle = PaymentBundleMock();

  setUp(() {
    container = ProviderContainer(
      overrides: [
        getPaymentBundleUseCase.overrideWith((ref) => getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock),
        createPaymentBundleUseCase.overrideWith((ref) => createPaymentBundleUseCaseMock),
      ],
    );
  });

  tearDown(() {
    reset(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock);
    reset(createPaymentBundleUseCaseMock);
  });

  test('test A', () async {
    when(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock.run).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(fakeBundle));
    final listener = ListenerMock<PaymentBundleState>();
    container.listen<PaymentBundleState>(paymentBundleVM, listener, fireImmediately: true);

    await container.pump();

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        () => listener(null, PaymentBundleLoading()),
        () => listener(PaymentBundleLoading(), PaymentBundleLoaded(fakeBundle)),
      ],
    );

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  });

  test('test B', () async {
    when(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock.run).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value());
    final listener = ListenerMock<PaymentBundleState>();
    container.listen<PaymentBundleState>(paymentBundleVM, listener, fireImmediately: true);

    await container.pump();

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        () => listener(null, PaymentBundleLoading()),
        () => listener(PaymentBundleLoading(), PaymentBundleDisabled()),
      ],
    );

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  });

  test('test C', () async {
    final exception = HttpException.handshake();
    when(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock.run).thenThrow(exception);
    final listener = ListenerMock<PaymentBundleState>();
    container.listen<PaymentBundleState>(paymentBundleVM, listener, fireImmediately: true);

    await container.pump();

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        () => listener(null, PaymentBundleLoading()),
        () => listener(PaymentBundleLoading(), PaymentBundleFailedLoadingState(exception)),
      ],
    );

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  });
}
```

What feels strange to me is that `test A` and `test B` work as expected, but the third one throws the issue:

```
Matching call #0 not found. All calls: ListenerMock<PaymentBundleState>.call(
    null,
    PaymentBundleFailedLoadingState(        [BaseException - handshakeHttp] null.
      Server message: null
      User message: null
      
          statusCode: null
        ))
```

So basically this test is considering that the first state of the `StateNotifierProvider` is `null` and after that, it transition directly to `PaymentBundleFailedLoadingState`. The question is, why the `PaymentBundleLoading` isn't being considered in the state stack since it's the first state emitted when the provider is instantiated? The expected state stack should be `null -> loading -> failedLoading` from my understanding, and not `null -> failedLoading`

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Randal Schwartz suggestion I refactored the code to replace `StateNotifierProvider` with `AsyncNotifierProvider` which reduces a lot of the code boilerplate and improves testability. I ended up with the following provider and test-suite:

Provider:

```dart
final paymentBundleVM = AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose<PaymentBundleVM, PaymentBundle?>(
  PaymentBundleVM.new,
  dependencies: [getPaymentBundleUseCase, createPaymentBundleUseCase],
  name: 'paymentBundleVM',
);

class PaymentBundleVM extends AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<PaymentBundle?> {
  @override
  FutureOr<PaymentBundle?> build() async {
    final bundle = await ref.read(getPaymentBundleUseCase).run();
    return bundle;
  }

  Future<void> createBundle() async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(ref.read(createPaymentBundleUseCase).run);
  }
}
```

Tests:

```dart
void main() {
  final getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock = GetPaymentBundleUseCaseMock();
  final createPaymentBundleUseCaseMock = CreatePaymentBundleUseCaseMock();

  late ProviderContainer container;

  final fakeBundle = PaymentBundleMock();

  setUp(() {
    registerFallbackValue(const AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.error(Object(), StackTrace.empty));
    registerFallbackValue(const AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.loading());

    container = ProviderContainer(
      overrides: [
        getPaymentBundleUseCase.overrideWith((ref) => getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock),
        createPaymentBundleUseCase.overrideWith((ref) => createPaymentBundleUseCaseMock),
      ],
    );
  });

  tearDown(() {
    reset(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock);
    reset(createPaymentBundleUseCaseMock);
  });

  test('test A', () async {
    when(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock.run).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(fakeBundle));
    final listener = ListenerMock<AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>>();
    container.listen<AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>>(paymentBundleVM, listener, fireImmediately: true);

    await container.read(paymentBundleVM.future);

    const loading = AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.loading();

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        () => listener(null, loading),
        () => listener(loading, AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.data(fakeBundle)),
      ],
    );

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  });

  test('test B', () async {
    when(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock.run).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value());
    final listener = ListenerMock<AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>>();
    container.listen<AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>>(paymentBundleVM, listener, fireImmediately: true);

    await container.read(paymentBundleVM.future);

    const loading = AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.loading();

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        () => listener(null, loading),
        () => listener(loading, const AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.data(null)),
      ],
    );

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  });

  test('test C', () async {
    final exception = HttpException.handshake();
    when(getPaymentBundleUseCaseMock.run).thenThrow(exception);
    final listener = ListenerMock<AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>>();
    container.listen<AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>>(paymentBundleVM, listener, fireImmediately: true);

    try {
      await container.read(paymentBundleVM.future);
    } catch (_) {}

    const loading = AsyncValue<PaymentBundle?>.loading();

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        () => listener(null, loading),
        () => listener(loading, any<AsyncError<PaymentBundle?>>()),
      ],
    );

    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  });
}
```